# Why do I sometimes get a free hit?

Tags: undertale-yellow

Late into my playthrough of Undertale Yellow, a yellow diamond occasionally started appearing around my heart during battles. Afterwards my heart would start flashing until I took a hit. Instead of taking damage, a shatter effect would play. Any hits taken afterwards reduced my health like normal.

Why am I sometimes getting a free
"damageless" hit during Undertale Yellow?

[image]